# Finding matches in c++

Tags: c++, regex

I have a string consisting of 1s and 0s, for example `11101010101011101`, I need to find index where repetitive `01` starts and ends.In this example its 3 and 12

```
      `1  1  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  0  1  1  1  0  1`
                ^------REPETITIVE 01-------^ 
               Starts here                Ends here
```

How do I find the indexes 3 and 12

```
string str = "11101010101011101";
regex rx("01+");

vector<int> index_matches; // results saved here 
                           // (should be {2, 8}, but always get only {2})

for(auto it = std::sregex_iterator(str.begin(), str.end(), rx); it != std::sregex_iterator(); ++it)
    index_matches.push_back(it->position());

for(int n: index_matches)
{
    std::cout << n << '\n';
}
```

Tried this, but it returns 3,5,7,9,11 and returns 15 too,but I dont want that. Is there a way I can come to know where difference of 2 gets broken, like difference between 15 and 11 is 4 so ignore 15.

Comment: It is not quite clear how you want to actually store the values. As start/end match position pairs?

Comment: It should not output 2, but 3 since that is the index of the first occurence of 01.

Comment: Actually, I want to store 3 ,12  as one pair and the last 15,16 as one more pair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the longest match, you need to use a greedy version of regex, also you need braces `(01)+` otherwise you are searching for 01111.... etc.

You can try the following out [here](http://ideone.com/IbeMqh), it outputs

> Success time: 0 memory: 16168 signal:0
>
> (3, 12)
>
> (15, 16)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string str = "11101010101011101";
    regex rx("(01)+", std::regex::extended);

    vector<pair<int, int>> index_matches; // results saved here 


    for(auto it = std::sregex_iterator(str.begin(), str.end(), rx); it != std::sregex_iterator(); ++it) {

        std::smatch match = *it; 
        index_matches.push_back(make_pair<int, int>(it->position(), it->position() + match.length() -1));
    }

    for(auto n: index_matches)
        std::cout << "(" << n.first << ", " << n.second << ")" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OP needs to get 3 and 12, not 3 and 15.

Comment: Aren't the start-end position values supposed to be grouped?

Answer (score 1):

Use `(?:01)+` instead of `01+`. The latter matches one zero followed by one or more ones, which is not what you really want.

Now, the `it` iterator actually provides you with start position (`it->position()`) and length (`it->length()`) of *each* match. And you've got two matches there. So you'd better collect a *pair* (using the start pos and the length) at *each iteration*:

```
vector<pair<int, int>> index_matches;
for(auto it = std::sregex_iterator(str.begin(), str.end(), rx); it != std::sregex_iterator(); ++it)
    index_matches.push_back(make_pair(it->position(), it->position() + it->length() - 1));
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/GaV428

Comment: I think OP needs to get the start/end positions of all matches. Your regex is correct, but it does not solve the code issue.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: oh, I see now. I'll update the answer shortly.

Comment: yeah This returns only 3 and 15, I don't get 12.

Answer (score 1):

Since your regex returns to you all the  following occurences (in this case the whole "01010101" instead of just the first two digits, you could try to read the length of your repeating 01-pattern.

Iterate over all matches, then return start and end point of the one with the longest entry.

I haven't run this code by myself, but it should be close to a solution:

```
auto words_begin = sregex_iterator(str.begin(), str.end(), rx);
auto words_end = sregex_iterator();
int length = 0;
int start = 0;
int end = 0;
for (auto i = words_begin; i != words_end; ++i) {
    if (i->str().length() > length) {
      length = i->str().length();
      start = i -> position();
      end = start + length;
    }
}
```

EDIT: I read your post as you need the longest occurence. Otherwise, my approach might be wrong.